# Proteins in Milk, Oat , Eggs and Soy

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, food, allergies

I have read that there are proteins in oat which are similar to those in soy, milk and eggs. I know nothing about biochemistry, and I'm struggling to decipher the info i find.. 
the closest Ive got to an answer is albumin - which i believe to be a group of proteins, all present in the above? 
Can you be intolerant to albumin? or a derivative of?

a simpilar version of the question - what is the name of the protein(s) found in milk/oat/eggs and soy, if any?

the reason for my question, my daughter has a milk/egg/oat (protein) intolerance and I'm just interested to find out if its a particular protein (or group of), or if its an intolerance to random things.

Many thanks!

Comment: Say, wouldn't this be better at [chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: @MARamezani Cross posting is [not frowned upon by the SE devs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules)

Comment: Hmm, I've nothing but to say thanks @MarchHo! Still, this question asks about proteins that exist in milk, and egg, and oat, mainly. Let's leave it to see how it plays out. Unless an answerer directly points at intolerance issues that can rise, with referring to something other than what chemistry can answer, this question will be off-topic.

Comment: @MARamezani proteins are biomolecules, allergies are a biological mechanism, why would this be better on Chemistry than Biology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allergies are often caused by the immune system reacting to [a part of a specific protein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitope), therefore it is in fact a specific protein in the food that is causing the allergic reaction to occur.

Milk allergies are caused by casein and whey ([Source: Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/milk-allergy/basics/causes/con-20032147))

Oat allergies can be caused by avenin ([Source: EJCI](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2362.2000.00684.x/abstract;jsessionid=EDDD28A3A4B53E6620A96673DCDFF59E.f01t02))

Soy and egg allergies are caused by their respective albumin proteins. Additionally, egg lysozyme can also cause allergy. (Source: [Cleveland Clinic](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases_conditions/hic_Allergy_Overview/hic_Food_Allergies/hic_Soy_Allergy), [Food Allergy](http://www.foodallergy.org/allergens/egg-allergy))